# Cannot install some packages with Pacman/Octopi - Suspicious execution method

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, gtk, artix-linux

When installing many packages with Pacman (through Octopi), I get the following error message:

> Installing selected packages...
>
> QApplication: invalid style override 'gtk' passed, ignoring it.
> Available styles: Breeze, bb10dark, bb10bright, kvantum-dark, kvantum,
> cleanlooks, gtk2, cde, motif, plastique, qt5ct-style, Oxygen, QtCurve,
> Windows, Fusion
>
> octopi-helper[aborted]: Suspicious execution method
>
> Command finished with errors!

It seems to be more a warning than an error, anyway it does not let me install the corresponding package.

I use KDE/Qt, but I have most of GTK installed.

I looked for a "octopi-helper" package to reinstall it, but could not find it.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

Using Pacman from the command line, everything is fine.
It must be an Octopi issue, then.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing with that error code is as you say, octopi related in its origin. Specifically, octopi is attempting to use a style called 'gtk' which is not evidently available to it. One way to address this would be to insure that you have something like kvantum or qt5ct installed and reinstall install the `kde-gtk-config` package, as these handle the sorts of situations where such a style would be provided in a qt5 application. You could install another one of the AUR's octopi packages to see if that helps, just be sure to enable the repositories as described on the wiki to insure you have access to as wide of a set of compatible packages as possible and in all likelihood the issue will be resolved.

You likely installed octopi using an AUR helper, which is a-ok in my book but because most of that is built expecting Arch not Artix, these sorts of annoyances will in time happen to anyone. The key

Comment: It looks like you left off in mid-sentence

Comment: A piece of your text is missing. Add it and I will accept you answer.